# Remove git commit that is not in history

Tags: git, github

I had something like this:

```
A - B - C
```

I amended C and I had:

```
A - B - D
```

And C in floating somewhere else, how can I delete C from local and remote repository?

There are no pointers to C. But I can read its hash in Github. How can I force the garbage collection and push this to remote?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [github support](http://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

> Be warned that force-pushing does not erase commits on the remote
>   repo, it simply introduces new ones and moves the branch pointer to
>   point to them. If you are worried about users accessing the bad
>   commits directly via SHA1, you will have to delete the repo and
>   recreate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be a bit more specific about what you really did, what refs (heads, "pointers") point to which commits, etc. before you can get a specific answer.

In general, if no refs point to your old commit, C, then it will be garbage collected in time.

If you have refs pointing to C and you want C to disappear, you need to remove those refs. Of course, you need to understand the potential effects of doing that - i.e. what other commits might disappear.

Comment: it will be garbage collected in time -> Couldn't one also run **[git gc --aggressive](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)** to force the pruning of loose objects?

Comment: There are a number of ways to force Git to do a garbage collection. Any of them will... force Git to do a garbage collection!

Comment: Would this make remote commits dissapear?

Comment: I don't think you can force a GC on a remote repo (unless you have shell access to that too!) You'd have to wait for the normal periodic GC to do its thing. Otherwise, you're left deleting and re-creating the repo.